# memory issue with couchbase server(4.5.0-2601 Community Edition)

Tags: java, couchbase, centos8

We are using couchbase server with following configuration
os: centos 8
version: couchbase Version: 4.5.0-2601 Community Edition (build-2601)
bucket type: Memcached buckets

We can not access the our whole server due to high memory. While we are checking logs we find below error in different log files

```
indexer.log
-----------
2020-12-30T17:39:36.998+00:00 [Error] panic in PeerPipe.doReceive() : runtime error: makeslice: len out of range
2020-12-30T17:39:36.998+00:00 [Error]     /home/couchbase/jenkins/workspace/watson-unix/goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/indexing/secondary/logging/logging.go:165 +0x24
github.com/couchbase/gometa/common.(*PeerPipe).doReceive.func1(0xc823bc0d20)
    /home/couchbase/jenkins/workspace/watson-unix/goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/gometa/common/peerPipe.go:192 +0xf8
panic(0xf29280, 0xc82341d8e0)
    /home/couchbase/.cbdepscache/exploded/x86_64/go-1.6/go/src/runtime/panic.go:426 +0x4e9
github.com/couchbase/gometa/common.(*PeerPipe).readBytes(0xc823bc0d20, 0x1b252d3132333435, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/couchbase/jenkins/workspace/watson-unix/goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/gometa/common/peerPipe.go:255 +0x8c
github.com/couchbase/gometa/common.(*PeerPipe).doReceive(0xc823bc0d20)
    /home/couchbase/jenkins/workspace/watson-unix/goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/gometa/common/peerPipe.go:211 +0x373
created by github.com/couchbase/gometa/common.NewPeerPipe
    /home/couchbase/jenkins/workspace/watson-unix/goproj/src/github.com/couchbase/gometa/common/peerPipe.go:60 +0x142

 

2020-12-30T17:39:36.998+00:00 [Error] LeaderSyncProxy.updateAcceptEpochAfterQuorum(): Error encountered = Server Error : SyncProxy.listen(): channel closed. Terminate
2020-12-30T17:39:36.998+00:00 [Error] LeaderServer:startProxy(): Leader Fail to synchronization with follower (TCP conn = 10.10.0.95:62288)
2020-12-30T17:39:46.008+00:00 [Info] Indexer::ReadMemstats Time Taken 776.105Âµs
2020-12-30T17:39:47.447+00:00 [Info] connected with 2 indexers
2020-12-30T17:39:47.447+00:00 [Info] client load stats {}
2020-12-30T17:39:52.323+00:00 [Info] memstats {"Alloc":57402672, "TotalAlloc":239502247224, "Sys":97601784, "Lookups":1103181, "Mallocs":4164125432,"Frees":4164027583, "HeapAlloc":57402672, "HeapSys":86081536, "HeapIdle":25837568, "HeapInuse":60243968,"HeapReleased":2400256, "HeapObjects":97849,"GCSys":2934784, "LastGC":1609349961539143885,"PauseTotalNs":6554226872, "PauseNs":[767905], "NumGC":7864}
2020-12-30T17:39:53.141+00:00 [Info] PeriodicStats = {"index_not_found_errcount":0,"indexer_state":"Active","memory_quota":536870912,"memory_used":63440896,"memory_used_queue":0,"memory_used_storage":262144,"needs_restart":false,"num_connections":0,"storage_mode":"forestdb","timings/stats_response":"1313246 100709227658 8965563527075018","uptime":"262h43m9.128529105s"}
2020-12-30T17:39:56.008+00:00 [Info] Indexer::ReadMemstats Time Taken 320.602Âµs
2020-12-30T17:40:06.009+00:00 [Info] Indexer::ReadMemstats Time Taken 394.903Âµs
2020-12-30T17:40:16.009+00:00 [Info] Indexer::ReadMemstats Time Taken 184.702Âµs
2020-12-30T17:40:26.010+00:00 [Info] Indexer::ReadMemstats Time Taken 383.503Âµs
2020-12-30T17:40:36.010+00:00 [Info] Indexer::ReadMemstats Time Taken 249.102Âµs
2020-12-30T17:40:46.011+00:00 [Info] Indexer::ReadMemstats Time Taken 511.404Âµs
2020-12-30T17:40:47.447+00:00 [Info] connected with 2 indexers
2020-12-30T17:40:47.447+00:00 [Info] client load stats {}
2020-12-30T17:40:52.323+00:00 [Info] memstats {"Alloc":71722192, "TotalAlloc":239516566744, "Sys":97601784, "Lookups":1103249, "Mallocs":4164375144,"Frees":4164103284, "HeapAlloc":71722192, "HeapSys":86081536, "HeapIdle":12656640, "HeapInuse":73424896,"HeapReleased":2400256, "HeapObjects":271860,"GCSys":2934784, "LastGC":1609349961539143885,"PauseTotalNs":6554226872, "PauseNs":[], "NumGC":7864}
2020-12-30T17:40:53.141+00:00 [Info] PeriodicStats = {"index_not_found_errcount":0,"indexer_state":"Active","memory_quota":536870912,"memory_used":76621824,"memory_used_queue":0,"memory_used_storage":262144,"needs_restart":false,"num_connections":0,"storage_mode":"forestdb","timings/stats_response":"1313329 100715623909 8966078509836069","uptime":"262h44m9.1288835s"}
2020-12-30T17:40:56.012+00:00 [Info] Indexer::ReadMemstats Time Taken 166.301Âµs
2020-12-30T17:41:06.012+00:00 [Info] Indexer::ReadMemstats Time Taken 180.401Âµs



debug.log
---------
ns_server:error,2020-12-31T14:51:19.184Z,ns_1@10.10.0.95:index_stats_collector-index<0.4315.363>:index_rest:get_json:42]Request to (indexer) http://127.0.0.1:84/stats?async=true failed: {error,


stats.log
---------
[stats:warn,2020-12-31T14:51:19.184Z,ns_1@10.10.0.95:index_stats_collector-index<0.4315.363>:base_stats_collector:latest_tick:69](Collector: index_stats_collector) Dropped 10 ticks
```

What is the reason of high memory?
What is meaning of that error in indexer.log?

Comment: Ask on https://forums.couchbase.com/, you will get better support there for this kind of question

Comment: couchbase forum link: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/memory-issue-with-couchbase-server-4-5-0-2601-community-edition/28956